# how to get the y axis in layout stacked bokeh plots again aligned with bokeh version >= 1.1

Tags: bokeh

I wrote a bokeh based package, to plot cluster heatmaps with as many horizontal and vertical annotation bars as needed.

- https://gitlab.com/biotransistor/bokehheat

Everything worked fine till bokeh version 1.1. Since bokeh version 1.1 the horizontal annotation bar align no longer properly. This is a major problem for my package.

Is there a way to get the before version 1.1 behavior back with more recent versions of bokeh? (the latest version is bokeh 1.4.)

This is a code example to show what I mean:

```py
# libraries
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, export_png

# gerenate bar one
fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]
p_bar1 = figure(x_range=fruits, y_range=(0,9), title="fruits", plot_height=128)
p_bar1.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=1)

# gerenate bar two
fruits = ['APPLES', 'PEARS', 'NECTARINES', 'PLUMES', 'GRAPES', 'STRAWBERRIES']
counts = [5000, 3000, 4000, 2000, 4000, 6000]
p_bar2 = figure(x_range=fruits, y_range=(0,9000), title="FRUITS", plot_height=128)
p_bar2.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=1)

# stack plots
o_layout = layout([[p_bar1],[p_bar2]])
show(o_layout)
#export_png(o_layout, filename="bokeh_plot.png")
```

With **bokeh 1.0.4** the output looks like this:
[image]

With **bokeh >= 1.1** the output looks like this:
[image]

The problem is that the **y axis no longer align!**
I am great full for any advice, Elmar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet with the new layout system is to set a common `min_border_left` value that is large enough to accommodate either axis.

```
p_bar1.min_border_left = 40
p_bar2.min_border_left = 40
```

You will have to experiment to find a value that you like best for your situation.

The old alignment was due to a complicated constraints-based layout system that seemed like a great approach in principle, but in practice turned out to be  unmaintainably opaque and complex, and performed very, very poorly (slowly) after a relatively low threshold of layout size. It was probably the largest source of issues and complaints before it was replaced with something much simpler and faster (but less automatic in some cases).

Comment: Thank you @bigreddot for this prompt response.
I just tested your code. And it works like a charm!
And thank you for the explanation why the layout function changed.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The new version 0.0.4 form bokehheat is out and works smoothly with the latest bokeh version 1.4. @bigreddot, I added you to the contribution, helpful discussion section in the readme file of the project. let me know if this not should be ok. 
best, Elmar